# ASP.NET MVC Remote validation hook method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Is it possible to add a hook method on the client side with a remote validation?
I want to check if an email is already taken and if that is true i want to add a button on my form that will show the user with that email address.

note I also check if email is required and or a valid e-mail. the button should only show when an email is already in de database.

(the validation itself works, I just want to catch the event and add a button to my view)

here is my code in the model

```
  <Remote("ValidateEmail", "User", additionalfields:="UserGuid,PersonGuid", ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(Resources.Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName:="UserErrorDuplicateEmail")>
    Public Property Email As String
```

my javascript

```
function createValidationCheck() {
$("form input").change(function () {
    console.log("change")
    $("form").valid();
});


$("form").validate({
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        console.log("TESTING")
    }
})}
```

this is part of my view

```
@Using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveUserDetail", New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "Post",
                                                                .UpdateTargetId = "displayContainer",
                                                                .OnFailure = "PostFailure",
                                                                .OnSuccess = "fillDisplayContainer",
                                                               .OnComplete = "userDetailFinished"
                                                              }))


         @<div id="detailInformation">
            <h2>@Resources.Labels.UserDetails</h2>

              @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.UserGuid)
               @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.PersonGuid)

              <div class="label">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Email)

            </div>
            <div class="displayForCorrector">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Email)
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Email,Nothing,New With{.id ="ShowEmailList"})
            </div>
```

In short,How can I catch the validation event and add behaviour to it via jquery?

Comment: I found the solution
Just add the following line
 $("form").bind('invalid-form.validate',addValidationInvalidHandler)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution

To add an event just add this in your Javascript

```
 $("form").bind('invalid-form.validate',addValidationInvalidHandler)
```

the addValidationInvalidHandler is my own javascript function that get's called everytime my form isn't valid

Comment: Great... this helped me. If you just check `$('form').valid()` it is valid but remote validation fails... this hook did it and allowed me to reset a loading spinner icon.